# Set the Notification alert style as default programmatically on Application with push notification

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application with push notification service. And I want to set the notification alert style programmatically for example: Alert style = 'Alerts' as default on my Application without Setting the notification on Notification Center. Is that even possible?

Comment: what do you mean i can got it :(

Comment: Hmmm. When I launch my application at first time, the default notification style on Notification Center(Setting>Notification>MyApp>on Alert Style) is 'Banner'. is it possible to set that to 'Alerts' programmatically on the app?

Comment: NO you can't do it :(

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible, it's up the user to choice the presentation style.